# Handling Errors in PRAW (Reddit)

Tags: python, error-handling, praw

I'm playing around with making an auto reply bot that scanns r/All submission comments for a given command eg. !command

When it detects this command it replies to the comment with a string:

```
eg. "Hello"
```

The error I get is that there is a limit on new accounts where they can only comment once every 10 minutes. And when the bot comments and moves to the next comment to reply to it gets this error:

```
raise APIException(*errors[0])
praw.exceptions.APIException: RATELIMIT: 'you are doing that too much. 
try again in 2 minutes.' on field 'ratelimit'
```

How can I detect this type of error so the code knows what to do, at the moment the whole script that stops and I have to run it again after 10 minutes.

Had a read of https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/exceptions.html but still not getting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Exception` is raised here, which you can [handle](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) using a `try..except`

```
try:
    the_api_call()

except APIException as e:
    print "Handling exception like a baus"
```

P.S. you would need to import `APIException` as it's not a in-built exception.

Answer (score 0):

As Samaksh Jain said,

used try..catch

imported APIexception using the following

```
import django
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
```

Comment: This is incorrect. In this case, the code throws a [`praw.exceptions.ApiException`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/exceptions.html#praw.exceptions.APIException), so the import would be `from praw.exceptions import APIException`.

Comment: @jarhill0 I did try that but no luck, the above seems to get it going for me?

Comment: Are you using django in your bot? Django's `APIException` is distinct from PRAW's.